# How does one reorder Asana tasks within assignee_status via API

Tags: asana

I understand how to reorder tasks within a project, but what about when working across projects? I'd like to use the API to reorder tasks set to 'today' as if I were changing their priority within the Asana web UI's "My Tasks" view.

Can this be done somehow via the existing addProject call, or some sequence of calls?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't supported - only (as you've discovered) ordering within projects. Dealing with things that aren't exactly projects (Assigned To Me, in particular) is something we want to tackle but there are no concrete plans as of yet.